# Getting back a C function name, not exported, from compiled code given just pointer.

Tags: c, macos, linker, symbols

I'm trying to get the function name of C function that was hidden, aka not exposed in the symbol table of an image.

I'm doing this on OS X and using dladdr and when dladdr returns success I check the `dli_sname` field, but its NULL.

Is there no way to get back the C function name? As I understand it, the C functions that are unexported end up being inlined?

Comment: If it's not in the symbol table, it's not available.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm able to do some appropriate casts to get a handle on it. What I want is to get the name as well.

Comment: The symbol table is the data that contains the translation between names and addresses.

Comment: @Barmar Darn, is there a way to at least get the type signature given the function pointer?

Comment: That information would be in the debugging information. But if you've stripped the executable, that gets removed.

Comment: C isn't like C++, which puts the type signature in the mangled name, because it needs it for linking to overloaded functions.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for the help and knowledge.

Comment: @Barmar one more idea, no way to abuse the linker in this case?

Comment: Functions that aren't exported aren't known by the linker. It uses the symbol table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way.

Inline or not, if it isnt in the symbol table, there isn't anywhere else names are stored short of if it was built with debug info, and even then if it were optimized it is still sometimes difficult or impossible to recover.

You can dump the symbol table with e.g. objdump if you are curious, anything that isn't there isn't available to you through dladdr.

Comment: Darn, is there a way to at least get the type signature given the function pointer?

Comment: @Edgar Nope. Same deal. That isn't stored anywhere but mangled names (and only if their mangling includes their signature), which goes back to it being in the symbol table.

Answer (score 2):

Unexported functions are not necessarily inlined (otherwise you wouldn't have a function address in the first place), but they're not in the symbol table, so they have no name associated with them.

There is no way to get the name, unless you export all symbols (e.g. GCC's `-export-dynamic`), but I guess you wouldn't be asking in the first place if you could do that. If it had debug info, it'd probably be possible to parse it to get the name though.

Comment: Darn, is there a way to at least get the type signature given the function pointer?

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian Nope. That information isn't available even for exported symbols (except by demangling C++ names), you have to protoype it beforehand (unless of course you have debug info).